# Importing a certificate says import successful but I can't see it anywhere in MMC

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, ssl-certificate

A client gave us their certificate, a `.cer` file. I right click it, choose install certificate, choose Local Machine and Automatically select the certificate store to import it. After a while (takes about a minute for some reason) it pops up saying the import was successful.

When I open MMC and the certificates snapin, and choose local machine, I can't find the certificate anywhere.

Did it actually import? If so, where is it? I would expect it to appear in the personal store.

This isn't the first time I've had this problem. Fair enough if it put it into the wrong place, but I can't see it in any of the folders.

Comment: You should find it somewhere in the `Trusted Root CAs` and/or in the `Intermediate CAs` stores.

Answer (score 0):

You have installed it on the local machine but not correctly in IIS, you need to go to IIS settings and import there as well. Depending on what you are trying to do, need more information on what you are trying to accomplish but I would assume your next step is adding it in IIS for website/adfs or something of the sort that communicates externally.

Where did you generate the signing request?